# Question on proving span of vector space dimensionally equivalent to $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am taking an introductory level linear algebra course and I was wondering if a certain convention to prove a set S spans some vector space V is valid.

Consider some set S = {$v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\in\mathbb{R}$}, with each vector having 4 entries as follows: $v_n = (x_n,y_n,z_n,w_n)$ and each constant $x_n,y_n,z_n,w_n\in \mathbb{R}$. I know if the determinant of the matrix of these vectors in nonzero, then the set spans the space $\mathbb{R^4}$ because the determinant is a 4-dimensional volume.

Therefore could this logic be applied to show a set S = {$M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4\in M_{2,2}$} (that is, a set of 4 2x2 matrices that are elements of the set of all 2x2 matrices) spans $M_{2,2}$ if the determinant of the matrix composed of $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$ is nonzero? Since the dimension of $M_{2,2}$ is 4 and the determinant of $M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4$ will be a 4 dimensional determinate as in the example with the real numbered vectors.

My intuition behind this came from reading this post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3382459/how-to-tell-if-a-set-of-vectors-spans-r4#:%7E:text=We%20say%20S%20span%20R,4%2C5%2C0). Furthermore, could this same line of thinking be applied to proving some set S spans some other arbitrary vector space dimensionally equivalent to $\mathbb{R^n}$?

To illustrate what I mean by a matrix "composed of the elements of a set S", consider:

S = {$v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\in \mathbb{R}$} with $v_1=(1,3,5,2), v_2=(6,4,2,9), v_3=(9,8,4,2), v_4=(3,3,2,5)$ The resultant determinate would look as follows:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
1 & 3 & 5 & 2 \\
6 & 4 & 2 & 9 \\
9 & 8 & 4 & 2 \\
3 & 3 & 2 & 5 \\
\end{vmatrix}
$$

Similarly, to "fit" the $M_{2,2}$ matrices into the determinate, each matrix $M_n$ initially represented as follows:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
would become $M_{2,2}$ = (a,b,c,d) and would be inserted into the determinant in the same manner as above.

Apologies if this post is poorly formatted or unclear, I am still trying to learn the proper conventions of creating a post on this website.

Comment: What is "the matix composed" of these matrices? How are you distributing the entries into the matrix? It matters.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I amended the post, hopefully this is more intelligible now. Thank you for the input

Comment: First, do you understand about basis and coordinates?

Comment: @GuilhermeCosta I understand that a set S is a basis for a vector space V if every vector in V can be written as a unique and finite linear combination of the elements of S. I also know that the requisites for a basis to be defined is that the set S must span V and S must be linearly independent. I have just learned this so I do not deeply understand it yet, but that is my current understanding.

Comment: Then you are just using an isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^4$ and applying the result for $\mathbb{R}^4$. BTW, calculating the determinant is overkill. It suffices to do row reduction and get it to upper triangular form. If there is a zero in the diagonal, the vectors ate dependent. Otherwise, independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $E_{11} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, E_{12} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}, E_{21} = \begin{pmatrix}0 & 0\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $E_{22} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & 0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}$ matrices in $M_{2,2}$. It's easy to see that every matrix $M\in M_{2,2}$ can be written as linear combination of the first matrices. In fact,
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}a & b\\c&d\end{pmatrix} = aE_{11} + bE_{12} + cE_{21} + dE_{22}.$$
Moreover, the set $\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\}$ is linear independent over $\mathbb{R}$ (for example). It's implies that $\{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\}$ is a basis for $M_{2,2}$.

Now considering this, let's try to translate what you did for $\mathbb{R}^4$ to $M_{2,2}$. First, consider $v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4 \in \mathbb{R}^4$ with entries
$$v_i = (x_i, y_i, z_i, w_i).$$
To calculate the determinant you pointed, in fact you consider first the basis $A = \{e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^4$, where $e_i$ is the vector with $1$ in i-th entry and $0$ in the others. So, the coordinates of each $v_i$ with respect to the basis $A$ is exactly $(x_i, y_i, z_i, w_i)$. This implies that the "determinant" of the set $\{v_1, v_2, v_3, v_4\}$ is the real determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4\\y_1&y_2&y_3&y_4\\z_1 &z_2&z_3&z_4\\w_1&w_2&w_3&w_4\end{vmatrix}.$$
This summarizes what we did:

1. Fix a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$
2. Find the coordinates of the vectors from the set with respect to the basis in item 1
3. Use the coordinates to calculate the determinant
4. The set with four elements is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$ if and only if the determinant is not null.

Now, let's try to do it for $M_{2,2}$. Let $\{M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4\}\subset M_{2,2}$, where
$$M = \begin{pmatrix}a_i & b_i\\c_i&d_i\end{pmatrix}.$$
So, the coordinates of $M_i$ with respect to the basis $B = \{E_{11},E_{12},E_{21},E_{22}\}$ is exactly $(a_i, b_i, c_i, d_i)$. Thus, the determinant you are looking for is
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
a_1&a_2&a_3&a_4\\b_1&b_2&b_3&b_4\\c_1 &c_2&c_3&c_4\\d_1&d_2&d_3&d_4
\end{vmatrix}.
$$
Therefore, $\{M_1,M_2,M_3,M_4\}$ is a basis for $M_{2,2}$ if and only if the above determinant is not null.

Everything we did here can be generalized for any finite-dimensional vector space just following the same steps.